# Meaning of derivative of function by absolute value: $\frac{d}{d|x|} f(|x|)$

Tags: derivatives, notation

What does the following Leibniz's notation of derivative mean?
$$\frac{d}{d|x|} f(|x|)$$

$f(|x|)$ is a function of absolute value of variable `x`.

I am OK with this notation and I know how to treat it:

$$\frac{d}{dx} f(|x|)$$

What is the difference between those two?

Comment: Where is the question coming from? $\frac{d}{d|x|} f(|x|)$ is a strange notation.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342073/fourier-transform-of-the-von-mangoldt-function/342096#342096

Comment: Or is it just a mistake by the author?

Comment: I would interpret it like with the chain rule $\frac{d}{dx}f(u(x))=\frac{d}{du}f(u)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}u(x)$. Here, $u=u(x)=\lvert x\rvert$, so I would interpret your expression as the middle term, equal to $\frac{\frac{d}{dx}f(\lvert x\rvert)}{\frac{d}{dx}\lvert x\rvert}$. Note that $\frac{d}{dx}\lvert x\rvert=\frac{x}{\lvert x\rvert}=\operatorname{sgn}(x)$.

Comment: it is some kind of distributional derivative, however I just have a very basic knowledge about distributions

Comment: More conceptually than my previous comment, it asks the question if $x$ goes up in absolute value, at what rate does $f(\lvert x\rvert)$ change by? When $x$ is positive this is no different than $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$. When $x$ is negative, going up in absolute value means becoming more negative, so you have the opposite of $\frac{d}{dx}f(\lvert x\rvert)$. That is, you have $-\frac{d}{dx}f(-x)$.

Comment: I like the interpretation with the chain rule, but not sure it really means this.

Comment: The notation $\frac{df(|x|)}{d|x|}$ means $\frac{df(u)}{du}\bigr|_{u=|x|}=f'(|x|)$.

Comment: Isn't it a little bit abusing of notation?

Comment: @azerbajdzan: Depends what you mean by "abuse". Regardless, this notation very common. For example, the chain rule states that under certain conditions, if $y=f(u)$, where $u=g(x)$, then$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dx} \, .$$For example, if $f=\sin$, and $u=x^2$, then the chain rule states that $$\frac{d\sin(x^2)}{dx}=\frac{d\sin(x^2)}{dx^2}\cdot\frac{dx^2}{dx} \, .$$The idea behind this notation is to treat $x^2$ just as you would a single-variable letter.

Comment: @azerbajdzan: I will say that the worst abuse of notation is unexplained notation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to define its meaning. Given that the idea of the derivative is based on making small changes $dx$ to a function and analyzing the resulting difference quotient
$$\frac{f(x+dx)-f(x)}{dx}$$

a reasonable definition could be

$$\frac{d}{d|x|}f(x)=\lim_{|h|\to 0}\frac{f(x+|h|)-f(x)}{|h|}$$

provided that the "limit" in question exists. By substituting $|x_0|$ for $x$, your “derivative” emerges as a special case.

Limit operations like $\lim_{|h|\to 0}$ are not addressed by the usual $(\varepsilon,\delta)$ definition, so we would also need to clarify what we mean by something like $\lim_{|h|\to 0}$. Using the standard $(\varepsilon,\delta)$ definition as a model, one possibility is to declare the following:

> For real functions $f$ and $g$ with "suitable" domains, we say that $\lim_{g(x)\to a}f(x)=L$ if and only if for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for every $x\in\text{dom}[f]\cup\text{dom}[g]$, if $0<|g(x)-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$.

Expanding $\frac{d}{d|x|}f(|x|)=\lim_{|h|\to 0}\frac{f(|x|+|h|)-f(|x|)}{|h|}$ with this definition, $\frac{d}{d|x|}f(|x|)$ would be the real number with the property that for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for every $h\in\mathbb{R}$ (the domain of the absolute value is $\mathbb{R}$),

$$0<||h|-0|<\delta\implies\left|\frac{f(|x|+|h|)-f(|x|)}{|h|}-\frac{d}{d|x|}f(|x|)\right|<\varepsilon$$

Of course, there's nothing special about the absolute value here. For a general function $g$ and some $x_0\in\text{dom}[f]$, you could define

$$\frac{df}{dg}(x_0):=\lim_{g(h)\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+g(h))-f(x_0)}{g(h)}$$

Comment: $\frac{d \sin (\left| x\right| )}{d x}=\frac{x \cos (\left| x\right| )}{\left| x\right| }$ Then according to your interpretation $\frac{d \sin (\left| x\right| )}{d \left| x\right|}=?$.

Comment: If you simplify the difference quotient $\frac{\sin(|x|+|h|)-\sin(|x|)}{|h|}$, you will see that it is equivalent to $\sin(|x|)\frac{\cos(|h|)-1}{|h|}+\cos(|x|)\frac{\sin(|h|)}{|h|}$. As $h\to 0$, we have that $|h|\to 0$, so $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\cos(h)-1}{h}=0$ and $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(h)}{h}=1$ imply that $\frac{d}{d|x|}\sin(|x|)$ should be $\cos(|x|)$.

Comment: Well that makes sense although comment made by @Joe under question explains it in one short sentence ;-). Nevertheless I accept your answer.